# Is possible to get all the values of all the <input>s inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

```
<div id="test">
    <input type="text" value="10" size="3">
    <input type="text" value="0" size="3">
    <input type="text" value="25" size="3">
    <input type="text" value="0" size="3">
</div>
```

I want a function to get all the values of the inputs. I was trying with this:

```
var inputs = $("test :input");
```

But I don't know how to go from there or even if it's correct.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var inputs = new Array();
inputs = $('#test :text').map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get(0);
```

Or:

```
var inputs = new Array();
inputs = $('#test :text').each(function(){
  inputs.push(this.value);
});
```

You can access each value like this:

```
alert(inputs[0]);
alert(inputs[1]);
alert(inputs[2]);
// and so on
```

The `:text` refers to inputs of type `text`.

Comment: Good answer. I don't think you meant to leave `get(0)` on the first one. It should just be `var inputs = $('#test :text').map(function(){ return this.value; })`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test :input").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr("value"); //Save value in an array or something
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `$("#test input)`

Comment: .val() should be preferred to attr('value') in case you want to get other types of input (like <select> or <textarea> elements)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
var values = [];
$('input').each(function(index, element){
  values.push($(element).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-jQuery version:

```
var values = [];
var inputs = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; ++i) {
    values.push(inputs[i].value);
}
```